# How to set in JMockit mocked properties to tested object on @Before method?

Tags: java, testing, jmockit

In a JMockit test, I have the following code:

```
@Tested
private PromotionsAddOrUpdateEntryStrategy strategy;

@Mocked
private BuyXGetYPromoPreAddOrUpdateEntryCommand precommand;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    initializeCommands(precommand);
}

protected void initializeCommands(final BuyXGetYPromoPreAddOrUpdateEntryCommand command)
{
    final List<AddOrUpdateEntryCommand> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add(command);
    strategy.setPrecommands(commands);
}
```

When the test is executed, then I get a `NullPointerException` in `strategy` object. Why does it happen? And what is the correct way to do this? The idea is to avoid the repetition of the `initializeCommands` method in all tests.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868690/wants-to-understand-how-tested-works-with-jmockit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the `@Tested` field so that it's initialized before any `@Before` method runs:

```
@Tested(availableDuringSetup = true)
private PromotionsAddOrUpdateEntryStrategy strategy;
```

See the [API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Tested.html#availableDuringSetup--) for more details.

There is a simpler solution, though, since support for injection of `@Injectable`s into a `List` has recently been added (version 1.28).
So, the following should work, with no need for a `@Before` method:

```
@Tested PromotionsAddOrUpdateEntryStrategy strategy;
@Injectable AddOrUpdateEntryCommand precommand;
```